# Auto Click Link by DOM Traverse, help please

Tags: javascript, dom

Please see the code below.

I want to be able to search a web page which will contain the following code, or very similar code.

```
<table class="fightTable"><tbody><tr><td class="fightClass"><a href="/profile.php?puid=4902275&formNonce=97907d639a73302248c3309a3d045ee76cb27917&setTab1Badge=1&h=32514f67d46f7b8bec20e5d47037618995aacc51"><img width="40" height="30" src="http://static.storm8.com/zl/images/vampire.png?v=330"></img></a></td><td class="fightMobster"><div><a href="/profile.php?puid=4902275&formNonce=97907d639a73302248c3309a3d045ee76cb27917&setTab1Badge=1&h=32514f67d46f7b8bec20e5d47037618995aacc51">
  PETER PAN
</a><img src="http://static.storm8.com/zl/images/indicator_mob.gif?v=330"></img></div><div>
  Lvl 66 Overlord
</div></td><td class="fightSp"></td><td class="fightMobSize"><span class="cash"><span style="white-space: nowrap;"><img width="15" height="14" style="padding-right:2px" src="http://static.storm8.com/zl/images/flesh.png?v=330"></img>
  102
</span></span></td><td class="fightSpLg"></td><td class="fightAction"><script>

    function fsb82308759() {
      var b=new Array(57,97,55,51,51,54,51,100,55,48,48,50,50,57,52,56,55,57,99,51,61,51,101,48,99,110,57,111,78,109,114,97,51,111,102,100,38,57,53,48,52,55,53,101,101,56,48,51,50,55,54,56,61,100,99,73,116,115,98,50,105,55,57,108,116,49,105,104,38,55,116,38,104,104,103,61,105,48,102,51,97,102,53,48,101,61,110,57,111,98,54,56,53,105,116,99,97,38,56,112,54,104,54,112,56,54,46,54,99,116,52,104,52,97,102,103,100,99,50,48,51,105,102,48,56,61,102,98,54,102,97,101,102,101,97,101,100,101,116,63,112,104,112,46,116,115,105,108,116,105,104);
      var p=new Array(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1);       
      window.location = c(b,p);
      return false;
    }

</script><a onclick="return fsb82308759();" href="/hitlist.php?tab=fight.php&action=fight&hitlistId=82308759&formNonce=97907d639a73302248c3309a3d045ee76cb27917&h=284e4fe4946e6fb8af3a662f4583454eebc8bd23"><div class="fightActionInner"><div class="fightActionInnerInner">
  Attack
</div></div></a></td><td class="fightSp"></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Basically, I need to create a script which will search the page for certain text, in this case it would be PETER PAN.

Once found, there is a link in the above code, at the end, labelled 'Attack'. The script I want to create, needs to click this 'Attack' link ONLY if the text that was searched for is found.

Now, I'm a novice at this sort of thing. But I gather this is possible through DOM Traversing? Please can someone let me know how I can do this? Or maybe provide a snippet of a script which will help me? Thank you so much. :)

So I created the following;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
var results = [];

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
if(links[i].innerText.trim() === 'PETER PAN')
    results.push(links[i]);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com">PETER PAN</a>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't actually do anything? It just loads a page up with a link of PETER PAN? How do I go about locating the PETER PAN text and then Clicking the 'Attac' link further down in the original code I posted? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all `<a>` tags you can do this:

```
var results = [];

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
    if(links[i].innerText.trim() === 'PETER PAN')
        results.push(links[i]);
```

Then you can check length of result to know if the text was found (you can break for loop if you need only one result);

**EDIT**
Give attack link id attribute like this:

```
<a id="attack" onclick="return fsb82308759();" href="/hitlist.php?tab=fight.php&action=fight&hitlistId=82308759&formNonce=97907d639a73302248c3309a3d045ee76cb27917&h=284e4fe4946e6fb8af3a662f4583454eebc8bd23"><div class="fightActionInner"><div class="fightActionInnerInner">
Attack
</div></div></a>
```

Then in js (under script that searchs for results):

```
var attackLink = document.getElementById('attack');
if(results.length > 0)
    attackLink.click();
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your reply. So I gather that will search the page for any links labelled as 'PETER PAN'? How would I then go about clicking the 'Attack' link (a little further down the DOM tree) after finding the text?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The only problem I have is that the coding on the actual page is live, I can't change it. I did, however, mark your answer as correct as it does work once the source code is changed. Thanks. :)